# Cmake: only install regex match directories

Tags: cmake

I have the directory structure of `src` as following:

```
src/abc1/...
src/abc22/...
src/abc3333/...
src/def1/...
src/def22/...
src/def333/...
```

Here I only want install `src/abc1`, `src/abc22`, `src/abc33`. And I use the following command:

```
install(DIRECTORY src DESTINATION include/myproj
        REGEX "abc.*")
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#directory):

> By default all files and directories are installed whether or not they are matched. The `FILES_MATCHING` option may be given before the first match option to disable installation of files (but not directories) not matched by any expression. For example, the code
>
> ```
> install(DIRECTORY src/ DESTINATION include/myproj
>     FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
> ```
>
> will extract and install header files from a source tree.

So, to translate this for your case, you need to do this:

```
install(DIRECTORY src DESTINATION include/myproj
        FILES_MATCHING REGEX "abc")
```